# Collection view with Headings on Top and Right in iOS, using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, multiple-columns, uicollectionviewlayout

I'm new to Swift and came across a requirement implementing collection view with heading on top and left.

**Headers Jan,Feb,Mar and Week1, Week2, Week3 are fixed on left and top**

Data corresponding to headers is dynamic and i get that from JSON file like in screenshot

[image: Year Statistics]

Not sure where to start with implementing this kind of collection view. Gone through many notes but could find only view with headers on top, but not on both top and left. Any code or reference might really helpful

AS PER LINK BELOW:
http://www.brightec.co.uk/ideas/uicollectionview-using-horizontal-and-vertical-scrolling-sticky-rows-and-columns
When I check in that link code..i get below error "Type Any has no subscript members" in method **-- itemAttributes** is of type **NSMutableArray**...i tried with guard to protect but failed.

```
override func layoutAttributesForItem(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes! {
        return self.itemAttributes[indexPath.section][indexPath.row] as? UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes
    }
```

.  ANY THOUGHTS PLEASE?

Comment: Are you going to scroll it? Or the collection will be static? If you want to scroll, would you also like to have sticky headers?

Comment: Your title and tags indicate you're happy to use either Objective C or Swift, but your description indicates you're using Swift. Would you clarify?

Comment: Ya content is scrollable horizontally

Comment: i can understand obj-c as well but my requirement is in swift..so any piece of code/advice would help

Comment: I have created a simple project for the same. Refer https://github.com/manirajaa/AssesmentCollection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can implement this by having collectionview itself as collectionview cell. If you want to implement this in that way then I can give logic also, if needed.

Comment: If a question is unclear, it is usually better to wait until sufficient clarification is provided before giving an answer. Meanwhile, answers are best not to include such requests for clarification, since there is a reasonable chance they will be left like that permanently.

Comment: That would be really helpful. Im struck on where and how to start with